# Cannot Push object to firebase using react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, set, push

I cant seem to push any objects to firebase. I am have a simple habit tracking app with a component that has a counter. Id like the component to send an object containing the updated count to firebase. I get the error

```
"Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {count, key, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."
```

I have tried updating state and pushing the entire state to firebase but same error.
I have tried on various inputs but same problem. I cannot push any data if it is contained in an object but I can push strings or numbers. I get this error when using firebases' push, update, and set functions.

a look at my `counter` code:

```
const updateCount = (habitKey, delta) => {
        const database = getDatabase(app);
        const dbRef = ref(database, `/${habitKey}`);
        data.map((habit) => {
            if (habit.key === habitKey) {
                habit.count += delta;
                set(dbRef, {
                    name: habit.name,
                    count: habit.count,
                    key: habitKey,
                });
            }
            console.log(habit);
            return habit;
        });
    };
```

a look at my submit handler. This works fine when `userInput` is just a string. If i try to push  an object however I get the above error.(with/without if statement)

```
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        // this prevents the page from refreshing when the form is submitted
        e.preventDefault();

        // create a reference to our database
        const database = getDatabase(app);
        const dbRef = ref(database);

        // push the value of the `userInput` state to the database
        if (userInput.trim()) push(dbRef, userInput);
        else alert('Please enter a habit');

        // reset the state to an empty string
        setUserInput('');
    };
```

link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Aa-thomas/habit-tracker/draft/twilight-glitter?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FDisplayHabits.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A27%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A31%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A31%7D%5D